# How to create horizontal stripped lines in a circle and respect borders?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I need to create a circle with horizontal lines and taking care of circle border.

Currently I've created this :
[image: First attempt]

Looks ugly. I've created a simple ellipse, and added a new layer above of lines. But I need to have this :

[image: Expected result]

Played with filter/fusion types and other things without success... Thanks for your help

Comment: Use Illustrator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use shapes.

- Get the **Ellipse Shape Tool** and make a circle, choose a fill color and a stroke color and width
- Get the **Rectangle Shape Tool** and holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> to subtract make a rectangle over the circle
- Select the rectangle using the **Direct Selection Tool** and holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> to Duplicate, move it up and scale it vertically
- Repeat with the next rectangles

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I was looking for ! :)